# Can I use firebase to implement login and auth but still deploy the project using Docker

Tags: firebase, docker, frontend

I'm new to web development and I am building a project with Firebase auth  for email/password authentication system. Is it possible to deploy the project using docker? Actually I want to use Docker to deploy my project. And I understand that Firebase Auth just provides the functionality to log in users. Does that mean Firebase Auth can use back end system that is part of Firebase?

Comment: Firebase Auth and docker don't seem like related technologies.  Email and password auth is handled entirely within the client app, and requires no backend. What are you trying to accomplish?  What problem are you running into?

Comment: @DougStevenson I viewed this page(https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) and thought it related to backend services

Comment: Only if you want custom auth, or you want to work with auth tokens on whatever backend.  The technology you use to deploy is irrelevant though.

Comment: But I always thought Firebase comes with its own realtime database and cloud service so the backend is handled by Google. I mean I can only use the auth APIs from Firebase but not its backend services?

Comment: The managed backend products provided by Firebase have nothing to do with docker.  You are not obliged to use them if you don't want.  You only use the products you need.  Firebase Auth doesn't make sense to use on the backend only.  It's primary purpose is for signing in users into your mobile or web app.  It doesn't really have an expected backend-only application.

Comment: It sounds like you need an overview Firebase.  I think you might be working with some bad assumptions.  https://medium.com/firebase-developers/what-is-firebase-the-complete-story-abridged-bcc730c5f2c0

Comment: Thank you Dough for your prompt reply. Yes I am new to Firebase so I might have mixed up some concepts. I will read the article. But actually I want to use Docker to deploy my project. And I understand that Firebase Auth just provides the functionality to log in users. However does it require a database to query? Can Firebase auth be used with any database?

Comment: I think at this point, you probably need to reword/rewrite your original question and ask again with your new understanding of how things work.